# What is the most efficient way of iterating over rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am working on a dataset with more than 10 million rows. As a part of data engineering process I want to update a column it the condition in other two columns is met.

I did it in the following way but as  the number of records is large it is taking a lot of time to execute.

```
    for i in df1.index:
       val1, val2= 0,0
       val1 = df1.iat[i,6]
       val2 = df1.iat[i,7]

       if val1 < 270.37 and val2 < 2.5:
          df1.at[i,'ppt_type']= 1
       elif val1<270.37 and val2>=2.5 and val2<7.6:
          df1.at[i,'ppt_type']=2
       else:
          df1.at[i,'ppt_type']= 3
```

Please suggest methods in which the value of a column can be updated in a efficient way.

Thanks.

Comment: [df.apply(function_name)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) ?

Comment: Is `df.index` a typo or do you really have 2 dataframes?

Comment: numpy.where() or dataframe.where() comes to mind.

Comment: @furas won't calling a function df.apply() have somewhat same execution time as for loop? I did used apply() first but the cell kept on executing for 2 hours.

Comment: @DeepSpace  Sorry its a typo. It should be df1.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.where() there you can combine different conditions based on different columns.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3},{'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 20}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

a   b   c
1   2   3
5   10  20

df.a = np.where((df.b >=10 ) & (df.c <= 30),1,df.a)

a   b   c
1   2   3
1   10  20
```